# How to implement view holder into array adaptor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

**Updated **
Hey guys I solved my problem by my own i used the https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper/blob/master/README.md
and pass UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image,ei.img_url); from my Entryadapter class and it works well.

I want to show Listview with 3 text and one imageview with separator/section in list.
so i follow this tutorial http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/?

than I face problem to load image (bitmap) so i use file and bitmapfactory to display bitmap on listview by using AsyncTask.

But problem is it loads every time when i scroll up or down.I want to display list once so i am trying to implement view holder for my list but as i am newer to android and Java i dont know how can i implement this to my code.

can anyone help me? I am attaching all code file so this code will help to other student and fresher like me.

here is my Entryadaptor.java

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;
Uri myurl;
ImageView image;
public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if(i.isSection()){
            SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);
            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
        }else
          {
            EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
            final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
            final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
            image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.showlist_item_entry_drawable);
            if (title != null) 
                title.setText(ei.title);
            if(subtitle != null)
                subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
                 if(image !=null)
                 { 
                 try {
                      URL onLineURL = new URL(ei.img_url);
                       new MyNetworkTask(image).execute(onLineURL);
                      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                      }}}}
    return v;
    }
  private class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap>{
         ImageView tIV;
         public MyNetworkTask(ImageView iv){
          tIV = iv;
         }
      @Override
      protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       Bitmap networkBitmap = null;
       URL networkUrl = urls[0]; //Load the first element
       try {
        networkBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
          networkUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return networkBitmap;
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
       tIV.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
        }
```

}

Here is fragment code

```
public class ShowsFragment extends SherlockListFragment { ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     items.add(new SectionItem("Today"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 1", "This is item 1.2","http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 2", "This is item 1.3","http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Image-New_Delhi_Lotus.jpg"));
        items.add(new SectionItem("This Week"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 4", "This is item 2.1","https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1080041262/VMIX_logo_zoom_bkbg1_normal.png")); EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(!items.get(position).isSection()){
            EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked " + item.title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```

sectionItem code

```
public class SectionItem implements Item{
private final String title;
public SectionItem(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public boolean isSection() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Entry item class code

```
public class EntryItem implements Item{
public final String title;
public final String subtitle;
public final String img_url;
public EntryItem(String title, String subtitle,String Image_url) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.img_url = Image_url;
}
public boolean isSection() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to cache the loaded bitmaps somewhere so you can avoid server calls if you scroll up and down (for example using a Map).
Also, since you are loading the bitmaps asynchronously, once you have loaded the data, make sure the view is still the correct one to set the image into, because views are getting recycled in a Listview (hence the name "convertView"). e.g.

```
    if (item.equals(imageView.getTag())) {
        // only set image if Tag is still valid
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Comment: I am using asynctask because each time findviewby id called at that time and it was making my app slower thats why i used Asyntask..at that time i don't know about view holder. view holder reuse the old view it won't call newer view unless and untill list is updated. so i will remove async-task and can you suggest me how can i use view holder in my code??

Comment: You definitely need to keep AsyncTask for loading the images, otherwise your App wil forceclose for doing too much work on the UiThread. I was merely noting that you need to be aware that things could change in the meantime. Always an important thing to note in asynchronous programming.

Comment: thank you can you guide me how can i store bitmap by using MAP and how can i avoid next time findviewby id ??

Comment: according to your solution i have to store that bitmap into hash MAP and than i have to show it into listview so when i scull listview how can i code that it wil not fetch from web but fetch from stored Map

Answer (score 1):

thumbs up for KoljaTM. it solved simmilar problem of mine. i use thread to speedup in gridview and i had problem that some picture positions are mixed eachother. after adopting KoljaTM's approach, no twist occured. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys Just this lib into your project and pass the image view object and url and done
https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper/blob/master/README.md